# Java-- How can I compare 1 array with 1 string?

Tags: java

Ok so I have this peace of code

and inside the if there is this while

```
           while (true) {

                  if (stringarray[1][a].equals(string2)) {
                     STUFF


                              }
       a++
```

the problem is that the (stringarray[1][a].equals(string2)) doesnt work, and I dont know why, or how can I solve it. It works when they are integers, or doubles since I can do arraystuff[0][a]==variable but it doesnt work for strings, what I am doing wrong?. Thanks for your help

Edit: Ok so this is the original (yep the array has 117 different values)
The array (a String defined array (String stringarray [][] = new String [2][117])
a (Integer, starting with 0)String string = new String ("")String string2 = new String ("")

```
          string = stdIn.readLine();

           while (true) {
                  if (stringarray[0][a].equals(string)) {
                      break;
                    }
                    a++;
                    if (a == 118) {
                        break;
                   }
           }
      }
```

If I were to put a System.out.println(a)
a would be 118 even when the text in "string" is correct and It should had stop long before

yet if what the while/if is a numerical value (example 2) the code works and a display the number

```
           while (true) {
                  if (intarray[0][a]==(randominteger)) {
                      break;
                    }
                    a++;
                    if (a == 118) {
                        break;
                   }
           }
      }
```

Then a would be the number I was searching for. 
For example if in the first code I enter the text hi, and the text hi is in number [0][15] then a would be 15, but it doesnt happen, in code 2 if I enter 482 and the number is in [0][34627] then a is really 34627. Hope this help

Comment: You'll need to give some more details. Like the contents of your arrays or maybe how they are being defined

Comment: try printing out the value of string to see what it is.

Comment: string1 is always what the user writes, if it mathces with something in the stringarray then a should become a number between 0 - 117, if it dont then it beacomes 118 and later in the program the user is told that nothing was found, when I try it with valid mathces a beacomes 118

Answer (score 2):

Well `equals` should work, but it is case sensitive. For case in-sensitive, try `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Also I am wondering if you have to use only index 0 then why are you creating `String [2][117]`. You can easily create `String stringarray [] = new String [117]`. This is only if you are not at all using index 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String txt1 = "abc";
    String txt2 = "ABC";
    if(txt1.compareTo(txt2)==0)
        System.out.println("Equal and same case");
    else if(txt1.compareToIgnoreCase(txt2)==0)
        System.out.println("Equal but may not be same case");
    else
        System.out.println("Not equal");
```

hope this helps

Comment: How exactly is `compareTo()` better than `equals()`?

Answer (score 1):

Please give more details about your string array.
Besides, if you define the array as:String stringarray [][] = new String [2][117], how could a be 118? when a is 117, it should throw OutOfBoundsException....

Comment: If you notice the counter is down the search code, so if a hits 117 and the search fails to find something (triggering the break) it keeps going with the if==118 breaking the while and not allowing to do a new cycle and thus the OutOfBounds never happens, its all abouth the order ;D